# Div Gets 0 Height Instead Of The % Of Its Parent

Tags: css

In the code below, div with red background gets 0 height when the image is there but with image node removed, it gets the correct height of 60px from the parent. Why is it and how can it be corrected?

Here is also the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/zuymamq7/

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
    <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
      <tr style="height:60px;">
        <td>
          <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:blue;">
          <img src="http://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/betterdays.jpg" style="width:60px; height:60px;"></img>
          <div style="display:inline-block;width: 10%; height:100%; background-color:red;">
          </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: The div is inside a table with a height set at 60px. Set that to 100% instead.

Comment: @Jhecht tr is suposed to be 60px. I do not want it to occupy the whole table space, just 60px.

Answer (score 1):

Biggest thing that I noticed as I began to edit this:

You added a close image tag (`</img>`). Those don't exist. The correct syntax is either `<img src="something.jpg">` or more technically `<img src="something.jpg" />` Threw off some things a lot (especially in the editor)

I'm thinking this is what you want, or at least, I hope.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:60px">
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:blue;">
        <img src="http://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/betterdays.jpg" style="width:60px; height:60px;" />
        <div style="display:inline-block;width: 10%; height:100%; background-color:red;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## Other Way

If you can change up the HTML a bit, then this should work too.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <tr style="background-color:blue">
    <td style="height:60px;width:60px;">

      <img src="http://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/betterdays.jpg" style="width:60px; height:60px;" />
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:red; width:10%">
      
        Text
      

    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How isn't it an answer?\

Comment: @Jhecht tr should be 60px.

Comment: It's a very poor answer and I really don't understand who would even consider voting it up

Comment: @JohnL. Perhaps I am missing something - if you know the height, why not set it?

Comment: @JohnL. Put the height on the `<td>` instead of the `<tr>`.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Well this seems to work but why? It feels wrong to add width to each td (assuming there will be more than one) instead of the parent tr element. Why does it not work when there is an image?

Comment: @JohnL. To be honest I'm not sure. I've always adjusted height of my `<td>` elements.

Comment: @JohnL. But `<tr>`s don't have widths. You would have to change the width of individual `<td>`s. And if you meant the height, then if you change the height of the first one, all the tds in that row will be the same height. BTW, why don't you add the 60px height to the div like Jhech suggested?

Comment: @KodosJohnson Yes, I meant height, I will fix it in a moment. Adding the height to div also seems like a possibility in this case but in terms of layout logic, it seems more intuitive to give the hard pixel value to the outermost container and work my way down with percentages .

Comment: @JohnL. In that case, adding the height to the `<td>` is probably the best option.